# I recorded Video for 30 mins, but it only shows 13 mins

Tags: android, video, android-camera, video-capture

I recorded a video by using third party apps in my smartphone for almost 30 minutes. But when I played the video, it only showed 13 minutes of the full length/duration of the video. Then I checked the video information on video properties/details, the size of the video is considerable enough for a 30 mins and the duration of the video is 30 mins. The only problem is, whenever I open the video, it only shows/play until 13 mins. Is there any way to fix this issue? By using an application or something else? So I can watch the full duration of the video. Thank you very much

Comment: It is possible that the stream is broken. I would try to play with ffmpeg and to skip bytes to recover the part after the half.

Comment: What are you opening the video in?  Have you tried other players, like VLC?